# Parameter conversion not allowed - MQL5 - CArrayObj

Tags: c++, mql5

I have the following object declared in my global scope:

```
CArrayObj *UpwardMovements = new CArrayObj;
```

And I want to add `CUpwards` objects to `UpwardMovements`. `CUpwards` inherits from `CObject` so it is possible to add it to the array. However, I cannot add it to the array in a method.

For instance:

```
void OnTick()
{
   CUpwards *UpMovm = new CUpwards(ColorForUpwards);
   UpwardMovements.Clear();
   CalcUpwardMovement(UpMovm);
}



void CalcUpwardMovement(CUpwards &pUpMovm)
{
  UpwardMovements.Add(pUpMovm);
}
```

I get:

> 'pUpMovm' - parameter conversion not allowed

If I do the same in my `OnTick()` method, it works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
UpwardMovements.Add(GetPointer(pUpMovm));
```

You may want to check the pointer before this operation with `CheckPointer(GetPointer(pUpMovm));`

Answer (score 2):

Using * vs reference.  Last line of OnTick(), change to

```
CalcUpwardMovement(*UpMovm);
```

Because that method uses reference.

---

Edit - 4/8

Weird ... does your compiler want another parenthesis? I'm just guessing.  I think it should not need another parenthesis.

Your code, with my proposed fix (see "change here" comment)

```
void OnTick()
{
   CUpwards *UpMovm = new CUpwards(ColorForUpwards);
   UpwardMovements.Clear();
   CalcUpwardMovement( (*UpMovm) );    // change here <<<<<<<<<<<<
}

void CalcUpwardMovement(CUpwards& pUpMovm)
{
  UpwardMovements.Add(pUpMovm);
}
```

Perhaps you did not mean to use the reference (I see you named the formal parameter 'pUpMovm', but a reference is not a pointer.  Did you change your mind one place but not the other?

Perhaps you want  UpwardMovements.Add(pUpMovm)  to be able to modify the local variable pointer UpMovm in OnTick() ... but in this code that would be pointless as the modified pointer would not be used.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I get this compiler error: `'*' - operand expected`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the error is pointing at the correct line. Maybe this is specific to MQL5?